# Silverlight object refresh on tab change in jQuery easy ui

Tags: jquery, asp.net, silverlight

We have a jQuery easy ui tab implementation in our project. When we click on the hyperlink button on the data grid of Silverlight page it open a new tab which is a simple aspx page. But if we click on the previous tab which has Silverlight control the tab contents reload. We need to stop the refresh of the Silverlight on tab change.

Comment: can you put some code of jquery and your html for the above question. Because it seems that the server controls postback is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the `anchor` or the `server-side-controls` inside the tab. You need to some how return false from that function which create tabs.